# How to reset an Arc in a thread safe manner?

Tags: rust

In rust, I have an `Arc<>` that contains a wrapping struct over an `AtomicPtr`, such that when the `Arc<>` is dropped, it will call `drop()` on my wrapper, and delete the pointer contained `AtomicPtr`. This is achieved via the following code

```
struct PtrGuard<T> {
    ptr: AtomicPtr<T>
}

impl<T> Drop for PtrGuard<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(self.ptr.load(Ordering::SeqCst)));
        }
        println!("Dropping ptrguard");
    }
}

impl<T> PtrGuard<T> {
    fn new(val: Option<T>) -> PtrGuard<T> {
        match val {
            Some(v) => PtrGuard{ptr:AtomicPtr::new(Box::into_raw(Box::new(v)))},
            None => PtrGuard{ptr:AtomicPtr::new(ptr::null_mut())}
        }
    }
    
    fn get(&self) -> &T {
      unsafe {
            match <*const T>::as_ref(self.ptr.load(Ordering::SeqCst)) {
                Some(v) => v,
                None => panic!("Nothing here!!")
            }
       }
    }
    
    
    fn load(&self) -> *mut T {
        self.ptr.load(Ordering::SeqCst)
    }
    
    fn store(&self, ptr: *mut T) {
        self.ptr.store(ptr, Ordering::SeqCst)
    }
    
    fn cmp_exchange(&self, expected: *mut T, desired: *mut T) -> bool {
        match self.ptr.compare_exchange(expected, desired, Ordering::SeqCst, Ordering::SeqCst) {
            Ok(_) => true,
            Err(_) => false
        }
    }
}
```

Now, say that I have a struct like,

```
struct Node<T> {
    v:Arc<PtrGuard<T>>
}
```

I want a way to reset `v`, such that it could track a new object/pointer internally with a new reference count, similar to C++'s `reset()` method of `std::shared_ptr`. This would decrease the strong reference count of any existing cloned `Arc<PtrGuard<T>>` by one when the reset happens.

What is a thread safe way to "reset" an `Arc<>` ?

Example of desired behavior:

```
fn main() {
   let a = Node{v:Arc::new(PtrGuard::new(Some(AtomicUsize::new(1))))};
   let mut b = Node{v:a.v.clone()};
   b.v = Arc::new(PtrGuard::new(Some(AtomicUsize::new(1))));
   (*(b.v)).store(Box::into_raw(Box::new(AtomicUsize::new(3))));
   println!("got {}", (*(a.v)).get().load(Ordering::SeqCst));
}
```

This will print  `got 1` , meaning the change in b does not affect a anymore. But I am not sure if `b.v =` is thread safe or not

Comment: Is the savings of "recycling" one really worth the hassle? Remember C++ has a lot of features that are potentially extremely dangerous if used incorrectly, while Rust  generally does not.

Comment: @tadman I don't see this as recycling but a lazy delete. This is part of a way to make a lock-free linked list delete operation. There might be clones of the Arc<> other threads are reading, but the delete should be lazy with respect to the linked list itself. Is it possible to drop the Arc and create a new one in the same struct ?

Comment: "Lazy" as in...weak reference?

Comment: Lazy as in the entire struct node doesn't not have to be deleted or removed from the list, only the `v` field is reset to some null or un-initialized state. But looking at `Weak<>` might be able to help here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not 100% sure exactly what you're asking for but it sounds like what `Weak<>` was intended to solve.

Comment: I added an example of the desired behavior I had so far for clarification, but I didn't know if `b.v =` for an `Arc` is thread safe.

Comment: `b.v =` requires a mutable reference, and hence no other thread can simultaneously also hold a reference to the same data.

Comment: `b.v = is thread safe or not` Yes, it is thread-safe. Arc would ensure this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this can't be done with an `Arc<>` because there's no access to the containing pointer inside `Arc<>`, nor is it an `AtomicPtr`, only the reference counting of `Arc<>` is atomic. This also cannot be done with `Weak<>`, because one strong reference must be kept alive in order for new `Weak<>` reference to be created, and that strong reference won't be able to be reset in any way.

In order to make it work where one instance of a smart pointer can be reset with a new pointer and counter, a custom smart pointer that has both atomic reference counting and and an `AtomicPtr` holder for the raw pointer needs to be used. The struct can be:

```
struct SharedPtr<T> {
    ptr:AtomicPtr<T>,
    counter:AtomicPtr<AtomicUsize>
}
```

The key condition here is that, `drop()` will only be called once per instance of `SharedPtr<T>`, when the object goes out of scope. It's impossible for the smart pointer to be cloned after drop has been called, since it's already in out of scope territory. Thus, this can be used to implement `drop()` such that it is only deleted once the reference counter's `fetch_add()` returns 1.

```
impl<T> Drop for SharedPtr<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            match <*const AtomicUsize>::as_ref(self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst)) {
                Some(p) => if p.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::SeqCst) == 1 {
                    drop(Box::from_raw(self.ptr.load(Ordering::SeqCst)));
                    drop(Box::from_raw(self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst)));
                    println!("Dropping");
                },
                None => {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For cloning, this is more straight forward. The internal raw pointers for `AtomicPtr` and `AtomicUsize` can just be loaded and stored into the cloned `SharedPtr<>`, since as long as `.clone()` can be called, the `SharedPtr<>` hasn't been dropped yet.

```
impl<T> Clone for SharedPtr<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        let empty = SharedPtr::<T>::new(None);
        empty.ptr.store(self.ptr.load(Ordering::SeqCst), Ordering::SeqCst);
        empty.counter.store(self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst), Ordering::SeqCst);
        unsafe { 
            <*const AtomicUsize>::as_ref(empty.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst)).unwrap().fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        }
        return empty;
    }
}
```

The hard part is reset. Resetting can be dangerous because in theory, there's no limit to the amount of times that `reset()` could be called on one `SharedPtr<>`. However, thankfully in Rust, values must be moved into closures passed into threads. As long as each thread has it's own clone of a `SharedPtr<>`, no two threads will call `reset()` on the same `SharedPtr<>`. Even if two threads call `reset()` on two separate `SharedPtr<>` that hold the same pointer, only the one that `AtomicUsize::fetch_add()` returns 1 to will be the one to drop the internal pointer upon reset. Thus, resetting would look like this (with a `new()` method for consistency)

```
impl<T> SharedPtr<T> {
    fn new(val: Option<T>) -> SharedPtr<T> {
        match val {
            Some(v) => SharedPtr{ptr:AtomicPtr::new(Box::into_raw(Box::new(v))), 
                                counter:AtomicPtr::new(Box::into_raw(Box::new(AtomicUsize::new(1))))},
            None => SharedPtr{ptr:AtomicPtr::new(ptr::null_mut()),
                             counter:AtomicPtr::new(ptr::null_mut())}
        }
    }
    
    fn reset(&self, val: Option<T>) {
        match val {
            Some(v) => {
                unsafe {
                    match <*const AtomicUsize>::as_ref(self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst)) {
                        Some(p) => { 
                            if p.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::SeqCst) == 1 {
                               drop(Box::from_raw(self.ptr.load(Ordering::SeqCst)));
                               drop(Box::from_raw(self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst)));
                               println!("Dropping");
                            }
                            self.ptr.store(Box::into_raw(Box::new(v)), Ordering::SeqCst);
                            self.counter.store(Box::into_raw(Box::new(AtomicUsize::new(1))), Ordering::SeqCst);
                        },
                        None => {
                            self.ptr.store(Box::into_raw(Box::new(v)), Ordering::SeqCst);
                            self.counter.store(Box::into_raw(Box::new(AtomicUsize::new(1))), Ordering::SeqCst);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            None => {
                unsafe {
                    match <*const AtomicUsize>::as_ref(self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst)) {
                        Some(p) => {
                            if p.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::SeqCst) == 1 {
                                drop(Box::from_raw(self.ptr.load(Ordering::SeqCst)));
                                drop(Box::from_raw(self.counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst)));
                                println!("Dropping");
                            }
                            self.ptr.store(ptr::null_mut(), Ordering::SeqCst);
                            self.counter.store(ptr::null_mut(), Ordering::SeqCst);
                        },
                        None => {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this uses `unsafe` rust, it does so in the context of some safe guarantees rust makes such as only allowing moved values or static lifetime references to be used from multiple threads. Additionally, `Option<T>` is used to symbolize a nullptr. A test for this smart pointer could be written similarly to:

```
fn test1() {
   let a = SharedPtr::new(Some(4));
   let b = SharedPtr::<i32>::new(None);
   let c = a.clone();
   let d = c.clone();
   let handle1 = thread::spawn(move || {
       c.reset(Some(5));
   });
   let handle2 = thread::spawn(move || {
       d.reset(Some(8));
   });
   let handle3 = thread::spawn(move || {
       let e = a.clone();
   }); 
   
   handle1.join().unwrap();
   handle2.join().unwrap();
   handle3.join().unwrap();  
}
```

Which creates 3 clones of an original pointer, but resets two of them to new pointers. This means only three raw pointers internal hold memory, and we should only drop 3 times, as the third clone still shares a pointer with `a`. Running this test prints

```
Dropping
Dropping
Dropping
```